# Class constructor raises TypeError

Tags: python

```
class employees:
    emp_count = 0

    def _init_(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        employees.emp_count += 1

    def displaycounts(self):
        print "total counts is %d" % employee.emp_count

    def displaydetails(self):
        print "Name :", self.name, ",age:", self.age

obj  = employees("krishna",4000)
obj1 = employees("shashi",10000)
obj3 = employees

obj.displaydetails()
obj1.displaydetails()
obj3.displaycounts()
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):    File "C:/Python27/dd", line 14,
>   in 
>       obj = employees("krishna",4000)
>       TypeError: this constructor takes no arguments

Comment: It is `__init__` with two underscores at the beginning and at two at the end! And: Please fix the indention of your code.

Comment: What about the indentation now?

Comment: Still a bit off.. Is it a SO formatting issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
def __init__(self, name, age):
```

is what you're looking for.

Also, you have to indent lines that are parts of functions, so

```
def __init__(self, name, age):
    self.name = name
    self.age = age
    employees.emp_count += 1
```

is more like it... and so on, but given the error you're seeing, I'm guessing that's a Stack Overflow formatting issue.

There are a handful of other issues going on here, but that should get you past your current roadblock.

Comment: actually the error is Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:/Python27/dd", line 14, in obj = employees("krishna",4000) TypeError: this constructor takes no arguments

Comment: @user2474432 I think you're seeing that error because the default constructor takes no arguments and you're trying to override it with `def _init_(self, name, age):` and subsequently calling `employees('name1', 42)`.